# Can I use this external light switch to supply an outside circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch, new-home

I have just moved in to a new home in the northwestern part of the UK. I have a light switch that switches an outside light. I want to use that power to have electricity in the garden including additional lights and a a waterproof plug where I can plug lawnmower etc.
I have opened the switch and I have 3 brown wires connected to the switch, 3 blue wires connected together and 2 yellow wires connected separately. Question:

1. Can I use this electric switch to plug safely a lawnmower or other items without burning anything?
2. Can I ideally have a double switch in order to separate garden electricity from patio lights?

[image: Switch wires]

Comment: Thanks for the picture! Those are "Yellow/Green" Earthing (Grounding on the other side of the pond) wires. The green stripe is significant (.vs. a solid yellow wire)

Comment: What I cannot explain is why I have a third wire for brown and blue. The outside light has movement sensor. Might it be from that? I have not opened the light to check whether this system requires separate wires

Comment: I would assume that power goes on to somewhere else from here. So you have live in, live out, and switched live, and the associated neutrals. I'm going to hang back and let someone more familiar with your local wiring standards get to answering the question, though.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, lighting circuits are normally separate from power used for other purposes.

Typically a lighting circuit uses cables with either 1.0mm² or 1.5mm² conductors, protected in the consumer unit by a 6-amp circuit breaker.  This isn't going to be enough to power things like a lawnmower, and it certainly wouldn't be appropriate to fit a standard 13-amp socket outlet on such a circuit.

The way the switch is wired means that you have permanent live coming in and going out again (that's the two brown wires at the top of the switch) and the switched live going to the light from the bottom of the switch.  The three corresponding neutral cables (blue) are linked together.  So it would be possible to have a second switch controlling external lights.

[For those in North America, 1.0mm² is a similar size to 17 AWG; 1.5mm² is a bit smaller than 15AWG.]

Comment: Its the same in NZ. But its also illegal to put a socket on a lighting circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the message very clear. Therefore if I was to add a second switch to control garden lights, I would have to double the live wire, connect it to the second switch and then run a new cable which includes connecting the yellow cable and have 4 blue cable connected right? Thanks