# How do I change an outdoor light fixture in to an outdoor 13amp socket

Tags: outdoor, light, socket

How do I change an outdoor light fixture in to a 13 amp outdoor socket

Comment: It is usually just a straight replacement, if it is a simple single cable setup.  Lights and outlets need the same live and neutral wire pair(plus ground).  Lights are usually on a switch, so outlet will be on the switch also.  We will need pictures of how the light is connected for more detail information.

Comment: I believe per a previous question that you might need to replace the wires, as a lighting circuit may be using smaller wires suited to 6A rather than 13A wiring, according to someone more familiar with your local standards than I am.

Comment: See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/272714/18078

Comment: Outdoor outlets usually require  GFCI protection.

Comment: If this is UK, it's not *quite* illegal, but it's unwise. Fuses/trips/wiring etc are not designed for 13A usage. Lighting circuits are often on spurs or stars not rings, so the usual wire weights don't apply in the same way. If you do this, make sure the socket is marked as being for the amperage the fuse/trip is designed for & never run anything heavy from it.

Comment: The GFCI protection requirement could possibly be handled by replacing the breaker.